# Choosing components in which states should live in react

Tags: reactjs

I am a react beginner,i got some concept difficult to grasp. How to identify states in react and how to choose in which component should states put?
I saw thinking-in-react example but I can't understand it.

Comment: check https://github.com/shabyWoks/shabywoks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are lots of good articles, blog entries even SO answers for that. You can find those and try to write some code. As you write your code with React you will understand where do you need state and where don't. This is why your question has been downvoted.

I don't quite understand the question "How to identify states in React" but if your component depends on a data to render and show some results, then this data can be placed in state. State changes, component rerenders and show results depending on the state. Think about the very basic Counter example.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0,
  }
  
  upIt = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
    value: prevState.value + 1,
  }))
  
  downIt = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
    value: prevState.value - 1,
  }))
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      Value is now: {this.state.value}
      <hr />
      <button onClick={this.upIt}>Up</button>
      <button onClick={this.downIt}>Down</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This component should show the counter value, so it needs to be updated with every click. Somehow either we get this value as a prop or hold it in the state.

Now, which component should hold state and which one should not? First read [this superb article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

This is not exact science but there are best practices. You will have smart or stateful components and you will have dumb or stateless,pure components. Smart components will have state and pass the state other dumb components to do something else. Dumb components will not aware of any state, hence they don't mutate any state, anywhere. They will get their data as props and do their job.

Now lets look another slightly complex example. We fetch some posts from an API endpoint and want to list each post one by one in our component. Here, we have two components: `Posts` and `Post`. One is smart, the other is dumb. Smart one does the fetch job and pass the posts to the dumb one. Dumb one does not know anything about state. It just knows its prop which is a post. Smart one does not do anything related presentation, just do its job and pass the data. Dumb one is doing the presentation job. Also, since it is not stateful we write it as a functional component, not as a class.

```js
class Posts extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" )
        .then( data => data.json() )
        .then( posts => this.setState({posts}) )
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.state.posts.map( post =>
          <Post post={post} />
        )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  postContainer: {
    border: "1px solid black",
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    marginBottom: "5px",
  },
  postBody: {
    color: "white",
  },
  userInfo: {
    fontStyle: "italic",
  },
}

const Post = ({post}) => (
  <div style={styles.postContainer}>
    <p>Post ID: {post.id}</p>
    <h4>{post.title}</h4>
    <p style={styles.postBody}>{post.body}</p>
    <p style={styles.userInfo}>Sent by user with ID: {post.userId}</p>
  </div>
);


ReactDOM.render(
  <Posts />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Let's go further. What if we want to read a post and make it go away? We already have state in our `Posts` component, lets improve it. Add a second property as `read` and write a fancy! function to add a post's id to this `read` state field. Then with a filter magic we hide those posts. Here, we also pass a callback function to our dumb component and with a button it passes post's id back to the smart one and this smart one mutates the state not the dumb one.

```js
class Posts extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    read: [],
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" )
        .then( data => data.json() )
        .then( posts => this.setState({posts}) )
  }
  
  setRead = ( id ) => this.setState( prevState => ({
    read: [ ...prevState.read, id ],
  }));
    
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.state.posts
        .filter( post => !this.state.read.includes(post.id) )
        .map( post =>
          <Post post={post} setRead={this.setRead} />
        )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  postContainer: {
    border: "1px solid black",
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    marginBottom: "5px",
  },
  postBody: {
    color: "white",
  },
  userInfo: {
    fontStyle: "italic",
  },
}

const Post = ({post, setRead}) => {
  const handleRead = () => setRead(post.id);

  return (
    <div style={styles.postContainer}>
      <p>Post ID: {post.id}</p>
      <h4>{post.title}</h4>
      <p style={styles.postBody}>{post.body}</p>
      <p style={styles.userInfo}>Sent by user with ID: {post.userId}</p>
      <button onClick={handleRead}>Set read</button>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Posts />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So, as you write React components you will understand where the state should live. But, do not struggle too much with this. Start writing your components, you are free to refactor them in the future.